# VBA for Excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet in which records of employee's and their various earnings and deductions like below:

```
Emp Name    Earning Code    Earning    Deduction Code    Deductions
John        Regular         5000       PF                500
John        Overtime        750        income Tax        250
John        Bonus           750        Loan 1            250
John                                   Loan 2            250
Peter       Regular         6000       PF                600
Peter       Overtime        850        income Tax        250
Peter       Bonus           650        Loan 1            250
Peter                                  Loan 2            250
```

I need to make another sheet in the same Excel with following format:

```
Employee Name    Total Earning    Total Deduction    Net Income
John             6500             1250               5250
Peter            7500             1350               6150
```

I am not that strong in Excel, so I am seeking any kind of help in achieving this objective. Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need VBA for that. Just create a simple Pivot table. See here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: You achieve with a pivottable. Employee Name in rows and Sum of Earning and Sum of Deduction in data area and then add a calculated field called Net Income which is Earning-Deductions. You can rename the fields in the output if wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure excel solution you can use Subtotal in Data Tab.

1. Select all your data. Go to Data Tab and click on subtotal.
2. Select your earning and Deduction column from checkbox like this [image]
3. To copy only the subtotals collapse the level 2 on clicking [image]
4. Select the data. Press F5 select Visible cells only from the dialog.
5. Press Ctrl+C
6. Go to your target to paste and do Ctrl+V in new sheet in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, pressing F5 is opening up "Go To" dialog box. Do I need to press anything else? I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: sorry missed that piece click on special in that dialog box and then u will get the dialog to click on visible cells only